# TCA9548A I2C Multiplexer with ADS1100 using python and raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c

I would like to use the tca9548a multiplexer from Adafruit:
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_TCA9548A

Together with the ads1100 adc:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1100.pdf?ts=1634723422799&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

on a RPI4. The tca9548 and the ads1100 are recognized fine using the i2c scanner provided by adafruit:
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_TCA9548A/blob/main/examples/tca9548a_simpletest.py

However, I can not use the smbus library to access the adc using this code example:
https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/ADS1100/blob/master/Python/ADS1100.py

Because I can not provide the tca[0] object to # Get I2C bus
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

it only accepts integers. Any ideas how I can use the adafruit library to point to the ads1100 registers?

This topic resolved it: [How to read from multiplexer with python I2C TCA9548A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335921/how-to-read-from-multiplexer-with-python-i2c-tca9548a)

Comment: Why don't you use kernel driver for at least I²C multiplexer? Or you are not using Linux there?

Comment: @0andriy Ok I see, so I can probably also use smbus library: http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/hardware/RasPi/RasPi_I2C.html to access the ads1100 behind the tca multiplexer. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: This topic resolved it straight forward: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335921/how-to-read-from-multiplexer-with-python-i2c-tca9548a

Comment: Which is really not the best solution. (I had also mentioned there in the comment)